# Selecting a ball probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are 11 white and 3 black balls in the urn. Balls are randomly removed from the urn until it is empty. What is the probability that the 8th ball will be taken a black ball?

Kind of stuck with this question, is Bayes' Theorem required here?

Comment: If you trust symmetry here, each ball has the same probability of being black

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 3 Black Balls on 14 total. The probability that the $1^{st}$, the $2^{nd}$ or the $i^{th}$ is black is always $\frac{3}{14}$

To have an evidence of this fact, and avoiding to do a page of counts, let's modify the request in the following:

Calculate the probability that the $2^{nd}$ ball extracted is black.

We can have the following situations:

$WB$ with a probability of $\frac{11}{14}\cdot \frac{3}{13}$ and

$BB$ with a probability of $\frac{3}{14}\cdot \frac{2}{13}$

The probability we are looking for is the sum of the two:

$\frac{11}{14}\cdot \frac{3}{13}+\frac{3}{14}\cdot \frac{2}{13}=\frac{3(11+2)}{13\cdot 14}=\frac{3}{14}$

You will have the same result for any trial....try, if you want, to verify.

Comment: Faster:  The chance that any given ball is the 8th selected is the same.  Done.